# getting a no hashes loaded error in hashcat, windows

Tags: windows, security, password-encryption, hashcat

I'm a beginner in cryptography and I was deciphering a list of md5 hashes using hashcat 6.2.5,
the problems that I faced were:

1. my cmd didn't recognize hashcat64.exe as a command but accepted hashcat.exe as a command
2. my text docs don't visually show the .txt extension but are indeed .txt files when checked with properties or path
3. decoding a list of hashes, I used the -m 0 and -a 0 command but when executed, gave the "token exception length, no hashes loaded" error. [image]

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: it would be great if you put some of the hashes to see  so we can investigate more

Comment: sure, 
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b